# Force single byte characters

Tags: bash, awk

This command works as expected

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {printf "%c", 0x7f}' | od -tx1
0000000 7f
0000001
```

However for all characters `>= 0x80`, awk is outputting 2-byte characters

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {printf "%c", 0x80}' | od -tx1
0000000 c2 80
0000002
```

How can I force single byte characters with that set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn off whatever UTF-8 locale you are using:

```
$ LC_CTYPE=C awk 'BEGIN {printf "%c", 0x80}' | hd
00000000  80                                                |.|
00000001
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk --characters-as-bytes 'BEGIN {printf "%c", 0x80}' | od -tx1
0000000 80
0000001
```